# Android have alertdialog not block app options menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I've searched around for a while on this but haven't found anything. I have an "about" option in my app's main options menu that gives the user support information (# to call, version info, etc). I also have an alertdialog that prompts the user to take an external action before the app proceeds (they have to do this). It's possible the user may want to get this support information while the alertdialog is present. Is there any way to make the alertdialog not block the app's option menu? Or maybe just show the options menu on top of the alertdialog somehow?

edit - not on top of the dialog itself, in the same spot it would normally be, just on top of the overlay.

Comment: I would use one of the alertdialog buttons to show the support activity.

Comment: Yeah that's probably the easiest option, but I was hoping there was a way to do it without the button. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with a dialog and sound. My problem was that when the dialog appears, it caused the original activity to pause, which had unintended consequences.

In my case I found it easier to implement my own dialog interface using a RelativeLayout and FrameLayout within the original activity.

Comment: Yeah I think this is probably the option I'll have to do long term, though time constraints are going to constrict me to JackTools.Net comment.